# Javascript check if each element of an object array is contained in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I ave two arrays with objects in them

```
var requiredfileds=[
    {name:'CVR', value:'cvr_code'},
    {name:'NODE POINT VAL', value:'node_point_val'},

 ]
```

The second array

```
var results = [
    {name:'CVB', data:[12,11,233,445]}
    {name:'CVR', data:[125,1,-45,4]}
   ]
```

Now i want to check to ensure that all the names in the required fields array are in the results array. So from the above two examples i expect it to be false and get the required field missing to be `{name:'NODE POINT VAL', value:'node_point_val'},`

So i have tried (with es6)

```
this.is_valid = true;   
this.requiredfields.forEach(field=>{
  this.results.forEach(item=>{
    this.is_valid = item.name === field.name;
  })
})
```

But the above doesnt work, How do i proceed

Comment: Try using `.every()`.

Comment: @Barmar `.every` returns true if all values pass a test, I don't think that would give the op what they're looking for.

Comment: Didn't see that he also wanted the list of missing names, rather than just a true/false result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `requiredfileds` by applying a callback function. This callback function tests if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)(any) of the items in `results` has the same name as the `item` in `requiredfileds`.

The result in `missing` is the filtered array which did not fulfilled the criterion (the one which are present in `requiredfileds` and not present, by name, in the `results` array).

If you simply want to know whether there were missing values or not you can just check the `missing` array length like this: `!!missing.length`.

```js
var requiredfileds = [{
    name: 'CVR',
    value: 'cvr_code'
  },
  {
    name: 'NODE POINT VAL',
    value: 'node_point_val'
  },

];

var results = [{
  name: 'CVB',
  data: [12, 11, 233, 445]
}, {
  name: 'CVR',
  data: [125, 1, -45, 4]
}];

var missing = requiredfileds.filter(item => !results.some(resultItem => resultItem.name === item.name));

console.log('Any missing: ' + !!missing.length);

console.log(missing);
```

Answer (score 3):

ES6 one-liner with boolean result value:

```
const result = !requiredfileds.some(i => !results.some(j => j.name === i.name));
```

---

A version with first item that does not satisfy the requirement:

```
const badItem = requiredfileds.find(i => !results.some(j => j.name === i.name));
```

---

If you want to have an array of wrong items, replace `.find` with `.filter`:

```
const badItems = requiredfileds.filter(i => !results.some(j => j.name === i.name));
```

Comment: i would also like to get the actually doesnt fullfill the condition

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI I made an update to get "wrong" item/items

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you want something like this perhaps:

```js
var requiredfileds=[
    {name:'CVR', value:'cvr_code'},
    {name:'NODE POINT VAL', value:'node_point_val'}

 ]
 var results = [
    {name:'CVB', data:[12,11,233,445]},
    {name:'CVR', data:[125,1,-45,4]}
   ]
   

var resultsNames = results.map(result => result.name)

requiredfileds.forEach(requiredfiled => {
 if(!resultsNames.includes(requiredfiled.name)) console.log(requiredfiled)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const entered = results.map(({ name }) => name);

const missing = requiredFields.filter(({name}) => !entered.includes(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmer suggested... you could use Array.every.  Combine with Array.some should give you what you want.

```js
var requiredFields=[
    {name:'CVR', value:'cvr_code'},
    {name:'NODE POINT VAL', value:'node_point_val'},
];

var results = [
    {name:'CVB', data:[12,11,233,445]},
    {name:'CVR', data:[125,1,-45,4]}
];
   
const answer = requiredFields.every(item => results.some(test => item.name === test.name))

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: this looks neater but the console.log gives only a boolean if it has failed but how do i get the failed object the one not in results but its in required

Comment: Sorry @GEOFFREY, I didn't know that was a requirement.  Looks like there are other answers that are better suited to give you that answer.